# LiveData - Observe objects in list

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have a list of`Functions` that is retrieved from a local SQLite database using Room and I want to observe every function in that list. At the moment I'm doing the following:

```
public List<MutableLiveData<Function>> getLiveFunctions() {
    if (liveFunctions == null) {
        liveFunctions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Function function : functions) {
            //Livedata with a default value on background thread (postValue)
            liveFunctions.add(new DefaultLiveData<>(function, true));
        }
    }
    return liveFunctions;
}
```

After a local fetch from the database, I can request the status of a given function using an RPC to my server. When I receive a response, I can set the new value for that function and I want my UI to observe the changes in that function.

Just some clarifications:

1. The difference between `LiveData<List<Function>>>` and `List<LiveData<Function>>` is that the first will only observe whether an object was added, updated or removed in the list, correct? It's not that `LiveData<List<Function>>>` also listens to changes on their items?
2. I'm using a `MediatorLiveData` to combine my observers to a "FunctionObserver". Is this the correct approach to handle all my function callbacks?

[code]

```
MediatorLiveData<LiveData<Function>> mediator = new MediatorLiveData<>();
List<MutableLiveData<Function>> functions = //functions
for (LiveData<Function> function : functions) {
    mediator.addSource(function, functionObserver);
}

mediator.observe(MainActivity.this, new Observer<LiveData<Function>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable LiveData<Function> functionLiveData) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Live data change: ");
    }
});
```

3. Can my code logic be improved? I know that I can request a `LiveData<List<Function>>>` from Room but I'm having trouble with my parent class having a `@Relation` annotation which needs the type to be a `List` or `Set` (and not LiveData)

Comment: Room can return LiveData on its own, why are you not using that? Wouldn't that simplify your problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate? If i try ```List<LiveData<Function>> getAll()```, I get a 'Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type'

Comment: There is an example of Room and LiveData interaction. Maybe this will set you on your way. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide. If that helps, you should probably simplify your question.

Comment: My problem is not necessarily related with Room. Room observes changes on the DB and reflects that in the data. I'm looking for a way to observe on every item in my list and I'd like to know if my implementation is considered a good/best practice